# What is the FTDI config for a Numato WaxWing Spartan 6

Tags: fpga, ftdi

Unfortunately I've overwritten the configuration of the FTDI chip on my **Numato WaxWing Spartan 6** FPGA development board.
I've managed to reset some values back, so I can at least communicate with it, but don't know what I've missed.

I have the ability to set values as I want, but don't know the correct values. Can someone answer, **what is the output from "lsusb -v -d 0403:6010"* for a factory configured Numato WaxWing Spartan 6 FPGA development board?**

** I think these where the original IDs*

Comment: Can't you just ask the manufacturer?

Answer (score 1):

I do have one of these boards and hope I'm not too late to answer your question. Here is my output:

```
$ lsusb -v -d 0403:6010
    Bus 004 Device 006: ID 0403:6010 Future Technology Devices International, Ltd FT2232C Dual USB-UART/FIFO IC
    Device Descriptor:
      bLength                18
      bDescriptorType         1
      bcdUSB               2.00
      bDeviceClass            0 
      bDeviceSubClass         0 
      bDeviceProtocol         0 
      bMaxPacketSize0        64
      idVendor           0x0403 Future Technology Devices International, Ltd
      idProduct          0x6010 FT2232C Dual USB-UART/FIFO IC
      bcdDevice            7.00
      iManufacturer           1 FTDI
      iProduct                2 Waxwing Spartan 6 FPGA Board
      iSerial                 3 FTLQK4S
      bNumConfigurations      1
      Configuration Descriptor:
        bLength                 9
        bDescriptorType         2
        wTotalLength           55
        bNumInterfaces          2
        bConfigurationValue     1
        iConfiguration          0 
        bmAttributes         0x80
          (Bus Powered)
        MaxPower              100mA
        Interface Descriptor:
          bLength                 9
          bDescriptorType         4
          bInterfaceNumber        0
          bAlternateSetting       0
          bNumEndpoints           2
          bInterfaceClass       255 Vendor Specific Class
          bInterfaceSubClass    255 Vendor Specific Subclass
          bInterfaceProtocol    255 Vendor Specific Protocol
          iInterface              2 Waxwing Spartan 6 FPGA Board
          Endpoint Descriptor:
            bLength                 7
            bDescriptorType         5
            bEndpointAddress     0x81  EP 1 IN
            bmAttributes            2
              Transfer Type            Bulk
              Synch Type               None
              Usage Type               Data
            wMaxPacketSize     0x0200  1x 512 bytes
            bInterval               0
          Endpoint Descriptor:
            bLength                 7
            bDescriptorType         5
            bEndpointAddress     0x02  EP 2 OUT
            bmAttributes            2
              Transfer Type            Bulk
              Synch Type               None
              Usage Type               Data
            wMaxPacketSize     0x0200  1x 512 bytes
            bInterval               0
        Interface Descriptor:
          bLength                 9
          bDescriptorType         4
          bInterfaceNumber        1
          bAlternateSetting       0
          bNumEndpoints           2
          bInterfaceClass       255 Vendor Specific Class
          bInterfaceSubClass    255 Vendor Specific Subclass
          bInterfaceProtocol    255 Vendor Specific Protocol
          iInterface              2 Waxwing Spartan 6 FPGA Board
          Endpoint Descriptor:
            bLength                 7
            bDescriptorType         5
            bEndpointAddress     0x83  EP 3 IN
            bmAttributes            2
              Transfer Type            Bulk
              Synch Type               None
              Usage Type               Data
            wMaxPacketSize     0x0200  1x 512 bytes
            bInterval               0
          Endpoint Descriptor:
            bLength                 7
            bDescriptorType         5
            bEndpointAddress     0x04  EP 4 OUT
            bmAttributes            2
              Transfer Type            Bulk
              Synch Type               None
              Usage Type               Data
            wMaxPacketSize     0x0200  1x 512 bytes
            bInterval               0
    Device Qualifier (for other device speed):
      bLength                10
      bDescriptorType         6
      bcdUSB               2.00
      bDeviceClass            0 
      bDeviceSubClass         0 
      bDeviceProtocol         0 
      bMaxPacketSize0        64
      bNumConfigurations      1
    can't get debug descriptor: Resource temporarily unavailable
    Device Status:     0x0000
      (Bus Powered)
```

What tool do you use to flash the chip? I just forked the flashing utility for the Numato Saturn FPGA boards and changed the description of the device. You can find my fork on [GitHub](https://github.com/modernrio/saturn-loader) if you are interested.